# FXML scene builder invalid attribute after filling ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I have this FXML file, where I tried to populate the ComboBox:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="650.0" minWidth="750.0" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="822.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="table.Table">
   <children>
    <MenuButton fx:id="dateFilter" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="55.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="114.0" text="Date" />
    <ComboBox fx:id="descriptionFilter" editable="true" layoutX="226.0" layoutY="55.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="204.0" promptText="Series Description">
        <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                <String fx:value="1" />
                <String fx:value="20" />
                <String fx:value="300" />
            </FXCollections>
        </items>
    </ComboBox>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

But since I populated it, it won't open on SceneBuilder and it displays this error:

**Error**

> ```
> java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Invalid attribute.
> /C:/Users/BTAP/workspace/Tst/src/table/table.fxml:12
> ```

And it won't load my Application:

> ```
> Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: FXCollections is not a valid type.
> ```

## Note

if I remove the `fx:factory="observableArrayList"` it loads on the scene builder and show a warning but still won't run my program.

And I don't quite understand since it's the same way as I saw in many examples [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065464/how-to-populate-a-list-values-to-a-combobox-in-javafx), [example2](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2486012?tstart=0), [example3](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tableview.fxml.html).

Why am I getting this error? Shouldn't it work?

I know how to fill the elements by code, but I am looking for a FXML solution.

Comment: Is &gt;=1 a valid attribute?

Comment: the error is before, on the line 12 i.e `<FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">`. And even if I replace those html codes for something else it still won't load.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need an import for the `FXCollections` class:

```
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections ?>
```

Comment: Please note that you also need the `<?import java.lang.String?>` import. (Which is already present in this example, but this not an obvious issue!)